# KeyListener Lags Inconsistantly

Tags: java, awt, keylistener

I am writing a little game in Java and, like most games, I need to listen for user input. I decided to use *java.awt.event.KeyListener* to handle inputs.

Here is my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    LevelViewer l = new LevelViewer(LevelFileIO.load());
    List<Entity> entities = l.getEntities();
    List<GameObject> gameObjects = l.getGameObjects();
    Pacman player = null;
    for (Entity e : entities){
        if (e instanceof Pacman){
            player = (Pacman)e;
            break;
        }
    }


    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(l);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setFocusable(true);
    frame.requestFocus();

    class Listener implements KeyListener{
        Pacman player;


        Listener(Pacman player){
            this.player = player;
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            switch(e.getKeyCode()){
            case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                player.up();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_D:
                player.right();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                player.down();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_A:
                player.left();
                break;
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    }
    frame.addKeyListener(new Listener(player));
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new UpdateTimer(
            entities.toArray(new Entity[entities.size()]),
            gameObjects.toArray(new GameObject[gameObjects.size()]),
            l), 0, 17);
}
```

That is all pretty straightforward, when I read key events I call methods in the player that simply change his velocity.

An example:

```
public void right(){
    this.setVelocity(new Vector2(speed, 0));
    this.setSprite(right);
}
```

The Timer at the end of the main method just calls this:

```
public UpdateTimer(Entity[] toUpdate, GameObject[] gameObjects, LevelViewer toRedraw){
    this.toUpdate = toUpdate;
    this.gameObjects = gameObjects;
    this.toRedraw = toRedraw;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    toRedraw.repaint();
    if (timeAtLastUpdateCall == 0){
        timeAtLastUpdateCall = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (Entity e : toUpdate){
            e.start();
        }
        return;
    }
    long newTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    double deltaT = ((double)(newTime - timeAtLastUpdateCall)/1000.0);
    timeAtLastUpdateCall = newTime;
    for (Entity e : toUpdate){
        for (GameObject g : gameObjects){
            if (g.touching(e)){
                e.setVelocity(e.getVelocity().multiply(-1));
                e.free(g);
            }
        }
        e.update(deltaT);
        e.getSprite().nextFrame();
    }
}
```

All this run function does is some collision checking and then calls the update method in each entity. In the case of the player it just calculates how much it should move since the last update call:

```
public void update(double deltaT){
    this.setPosition(this.getPosition().add(velocity.multiply(deltaT)));
}
```

Now the problem is that when I press a key that changes the players velocity the change will usually occur instantaneously, but sometimes there can be noticeable lag (around a quarter of a second, much more than 17 ms).

Is this a problem with Java's KeyListener, or with my implementation?

I would like to fix this to have smooth user input.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an issue with `KeyListener`. I am not a game developer but some things to consider:

1. Have you timed how long it takes to do the `TimerTask`? If it's ever over 17ms then it could be a problem especially when you compare [schedule](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)) to [scheduleAtFixedRate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)
2. You may want to use a proper [game loop](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html) particularly if you plan on this game being played on systems out side of your control.